# How can I remove already rendered unneeded Views instead of rendering needed Views?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am working on a **CustomForEach** which would act and work like a normal ForEach in SwiftUI, this **CustomForEach** has it own early days and it has some issues for use for me, which makes me to learn more about SwiftUI and challenge me to try to solve the issues, one of this issues is finding a way to destroy the unneeded Views instated of rendering all needed Views!

Currently when I update **lowerBound** the **CustomForEach** starts rendering for new range which is understandable. But the new range need less Views than before and that is not understandable to rendering them again for already rendered Views.

**Goal:** I want find a way to stop rendering all needed Views because they are already exist and there is no need to rendering again, and just removing the unneeded Views. And also I do **not** want start an another **expensive** calculation inside **CustomForEach** for finding out if the Views already exist!

```
struct TextView: View {
    let string: String

    var body: some View {            
        print("rendering " + string)
        return HStack {
            Text(string)
            Circle().fill(Color.red).frame(width: 5, height: 5, alignment: .center)
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
struct CustomForEachView<Content: View>: View {
    private let id: Int
    let range: ClosedRange<Int>
    let content: (Int) -> Content
    
    init(range: ClosedRange<Int>, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Int) -> Content) {
        self.id = range.lowerBound
        self.range = range
        self.content = content
    }
    
    // The issue is rendering all existed Views when lower Bound get updated, even we do not need to render new View in updating lower Bound!
    
    var body: some View {
        content(range.lowerBound)
        if let suffixRange = suffix(of: range) { 
            CustomForEachView(range: suffixRange, content: content)
        }
    }
    
    private func suffix(of range: ClosedRange<Int>) -> ClosedRange<Int>? {
        return (range.count > 1) ? (range.lowerBound + 1)...range.upperBound : nil
    }
}
```

---

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var lowerBound: Int = -2
    @State private var upperBound: Int = 2
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            CustomForEachView(range: lowerBound...upperBound) { item in
                TextView(string: item.description)                    
            }
        }
        
        HStack {
            Button("add lowerBound") { lowerBound += 1 }
            Spacer()
            Button("add upperBound") { upperBound += 1 }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Standard ForEach uses `id` of `data` to detect if corresponding view is present, so you can go same way.

Comment: yes, I also made an id constant as private, it should help to find the answer!

Comment: What is the reason for creating the `CustomForEachView`?  Is it to just make it easier to use `ForEach`?

Comment: yes, also other things like learning and more control in process

Comment: I am still unable to stop unneeded renders in SwiftUI, if some one got an idea or example code for it I would more than happy to try it. thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, one thing important thing to understand is that a `SwiftUI.View` struct is **not** a view instance that is rendered on the screen. It's merely a description of the desired view hierarchy. The `SwiftUI.View` instances are going to be recreated and torn down *a lot* by the framework anyway.

The SwiftUI framework takes care of the actual rendering. It might use UIViews for this, or it might not. That's an implementation detail you shouldn't need to worry about in most cases.

---

That said, you might be able to help the framework by adding explicit ids to the views by using the `id` modifier. That way SwiftUI can use that to keep track of which view is which.

But, I'm not sure if that would actually help. Just an idea.

Comment: Thank you for your idea, I am working on SwiftUI and I am not interested for UIKit, I believe it must be an answer for my question out there related to `id` as you said.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? I know you're working with SwiftUI. I don't think you can easily force SwiftUI to reuse certain views except for giving them an explicit `id`. Did you try it?

Comment: yes, As I see in my question I add `id` to codes in first place and also I used `.id()` modifier before asking the question, since did not solved the issue, I removed that modifier to make it more clear code to start solving issue. Also I tried other thing with `id` to finding the answer but it could not solve the issue, I think I was missing some thing in between.

Comment: How do you know it did not "solve the issue"? How are you measuring/inspecting which views are rendered by the SwiftUI framework?

Comment: Now it get more complicated I guess! I believe I should work on EquatableView part! in other words at the end of the day I should say or show or tell to SwiftUI how it can compare Views, do you think that for answering the current question I should find the answer of how can SwiftUI know the deference of View for render it or use it the same way? I talking about a CustomEquatableView!